# How do i profile the performance of nunit tests that are run through resharper?

Tags: nunit, resharper, profiler

I'm using resharper to run my nunit tests - and i'd like to improve performance

I know that resharper uses a built in version of nunit. How do i set up resharper/nunit, such that i can run my unit tests through a profiler and see where i can best spend my time when optimizing?

Comment: Which profiling tool do you have/want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with dotTrace you can profile Nunit tests right from Visual Studio or Rider, you don't need to use attaching: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiling_Guidelines__Profiling_Unit_Tests.html
Please note that dotTrace is a part of ReSharper Ultimate package, you need to have the corresponding license.

Answer (score 0):

I profile my code with [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/). You can start your tests and profile it with dotTrace (I start the test and attach the dotTrace to it). Second option is to use [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8). I would put StopWatch lines that I want to profile and print the values and depending on the results, I would start analyzing the code.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// code that you want to measure
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

These are the things that comes to my mind.